# jquery $get ajax call not always waiting for response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax call as follows...

```
$(".eetag").each(function(){
    var currentItem = $(this);
    var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
    $.get('service/transactionCategoryByKeyword.json',{'phrase': desc}, function(data){
        //alert(":" + desc + ":" + data.tranCategoryCode);
        $(currentItem).tagsinput('add', data);
    });
});
```

It sometimes works and sometimes doesn't and I think it is because I haven't told it to wait until success? Is that right? Can someone suggest how the call should be written?

**---EDIT---**

Thanks everyone. I've re-written the ajax call after doing some research and it is much better but I still sometimes see that the ajax is not waiting. In particular it only happens (i.e. does not wait) for the first eetag on my page. Have I re-written it properly?

```
$(".eetag").each(function(){
    var currentItem = $(this);
    var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'service/transactionCategoryByKeyword.json',           
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: {'phrase': desc},     
        success: function(data) {
            $(currentItem).tagsinput('add', data);
        }
    });     
});
```

thanks

Comment: it wont. Because it is an asynchronous function

Comment: You're going to need to use the `$.ajax()` function and set the aynsc option to false if you want it to finish before executing the rest of your code.

Comment: I've had a go at fixing it based on your comments and it is working almost all the time now but I do notice on occasion it still does not seem to wait. Have I got something missing?

Comment: I've edited my post again. The only issue I have now is that on rare occasions for the first eetag on the page I sometimes don't get a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could recursively iterate over the .eetags. This way the eetags would be processed one after another.

```
function recursiveAjaxCall(elements, index, callback) {
    if(index < elements.length) {
        var currentItem = elements[index];
        var desc = $(currentItem).attr('data-desc');
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'service/transactionCategoryByKeyword.json',
            data: {'phrase': desc},
            success: function(data) {
                $(currentItem).tagsinput('add', data);
                recursiveAjaxCall(elements, index+1, callback);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                recursiveAjaxCall(elements, index+1, callback);
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
}


var elements = $(".eetag");
recursiveAjaxCall(elements, 0, function() {
    //done
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, Just before you posted your answer I tried something similar but without the recursiveness (see my edit), Why do you suggest that we need a recursive call?

Comment: That's usually how I solve that problem. I wasn't aware that jQuery.ajax() had an async option. Your solution is more straight forward so I would stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using[`when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
$(".eetag").each(function(){
  var currentItem = $(this);
  var desc = $(this).attr('data-desc');
  $.when($.get('service/transactionCategoryByKeyword.json',{'phrase': desc})).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //alert(":" + desc + ":" + data.tranCategoryCode);
    $(currentItem).tagsinput('add', data);
  });
});
```